# Helm when variable child key does not exist fallback to default next variable

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Using Helm v3 the following template is breaking with error:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: rabbitmq/templates/secrets.yaml:4:31: executing "rabbitmq/templates/secrets.yaml" at <.Values.global.rabbitmq.password>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.rabbitmq
```

Contents of `rabbitmq/templates/secrets.yaml`:

```
{{- $def := index .Values "default" -}}
apiVersion: v1
data:
  rabbitmq-password: {{ $def.global.rabbitmq.password | default $def.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD | b64enc | quote }}
  rabbitmq-erlang-cookie: {{ randAlphaNum 20 | b64enc | quote }}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-password
type: Opaque
```

This works when `.Values.global.{}` exists. **However when `.Values.global` does not exist it does not fallback to `$def.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD` as I would expect.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the variable `$def` is always `.Values.default` (that is, whatever's under the top-level key `default:` in the `values.yaml` file).  That's probably not what you want.

The pattern I've found successful here is to set a variable for each level of the hierarchy, defaulting it to an empty dictionary if it doesn't exist.  That will let you do recursive lookups.

I'm guessing, when you say `$def.global`, you really mean the top-level `.Values.global` object, which has special meaning in a Helm subchart context.  So you could do these lookups safely like:

```yaml
{{- $def := .Values.default | default dict }}
{{- $global := .Values.global | default dict }}
{{- $rabbitmq := $global.rabbitmq | default dict }}
rabbitmq-password: {{ $rabbitmq.password | default $def.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD | b64enc | quote }}
```